# Update properties in POPUP , with leaflet and geoJson

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup, geojson

I've made a script based on : [update properties of geojson to use it with leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738805/update-properties-of-geojson-to-use-it-with-leaflet/64625139#64625139)

[>>>Working script picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GByyB.jpg)

But I have an issue with multiple arguments.. I'd like to put 2 separate variables like:

```
layer.feature.properties.desc = content.value;
layer.feature.properties.number = content2.value;
```

But

```
layer.bindPopup(content).openPopup()
```

can open only one - "content", there is an error when I put for example:

```
layer.bindPopup(content + content2).openPopup();
```

[>>> Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geOs4.jpg)

So I made another script:

```
function addPopup(layer)
{let popupContent = 
'<form>' + 
'Description:<br><input type="text" id="input_desc"><br>' +
'Name:<br><input type="text" id="input_cena"><br>' +
'</form>';

layer.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup();
document.addEventListener("keyup", function() {

link = document.getElementById("input_desc").value;
cena = document.getElementById("input_cena").value;

layer.feature.properties.link = link;
layer.feature.properties.cena = cena;   
}); 
};
```

[>>>Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNeBG.jpg)

But unfortunately:

```
layer.feature.properties.link = link;
layer.feature.properties.cena = cena;
```

Is the same for each drawn geometry. Moreover when user fill the form, the arguments will dissaper just after close PopUp..  With [update properties of geojson to use it with leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738805/update-properties-of-geojson-to-use-it-with-leaflet/64625139#64625139) script inscribed argument is visible each time when user "click" on PupUp

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the listener in the `popupopen` event.
Change your `addPopup` function to:

```
var openLayer;
function addPopup(layer){
  let popupContent = 
  '<form>' + 
  'Description:<br><input type="text" id="input_desc"><br>' +
  'Name:<br><input type="text" id="input_cena"><br>' +
  '</form>';
  
  layer.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup();
  
  layer.on("popupopen", function (e) {
    var _layer = e.popup._source;
    if(!_layer.feature){
        _layer.feature = {
        properties: {}
      };
    }
    document.getElementById("input_desc").value = _layer.feature.properties.link || "";
    document.getElementById("input_cena").value = _layer.feature.properties.cena || "";
    document.getElementById("input_desc").focus();
    openLayer = _layer;
  });
  
  layer.on("popupclose", function (e) {
    openLayer = undefined;
  })
  
};

L.DomEvent.on(document,"keyup",function(){
  if(openLayer){
    link = document.getElementById("input_desc").value;
    cena = document.getElementById("input_cena").value;

    openLayer.feature.properties.link = link;
    openLayer.feature.properties.cena = cena;   
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/ntvzx7cs/

Comment: Thank your for the answer but script above still give same values for each geometry. Let me know if it is posible to edit code belowe adding 2nd textarea :                                      
  `code` function addPopup(layer) {


  var content = document.createElement(["textarea"]);
  var y = document.createElement(["textarea"]);
 
 content.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
      layer.feature.properties.link = content.value;

    });
    
   layer.bindPopup(content).openPopup();
 
 
 

}

Comment: @MateuszKruk yeah you are right, it was wrong. I updated the code and fixed the example

Comment: Thank you, it works!. But let me know is it possible to modify the code below with the same result ? I mean double text area for 2 separate properies?  [link] https://jsfiddle.net/mattiaccat/1ufa2cyw/1/ [link]

Comment: Here: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/ntvzx7cs/) you have to change `input` to `textarea`. I recommand to use my code and not the code from your fiddle, because it makes it more difficult to add two DOM Elements (`createElement`)  instead of adding html text. Please don't forget to accept this answer

Comment: Thank you for helping me and really quick answers!