# Leaflet Draw not taking properties when converting FeatureGroup to GeoJson

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm unable to convert my Layer properties into the properties of the GEOJson object using Leaflet(0.7.7)/Leaflet.Draw(latest). My workflow is:

1 Create Map: `var map = L.map('#map', options);`

2 Create a FeatureGroup: `features= new L.FeatureGroup();`

3 Add to the Leaflet Map:  `map.addLayer(features);`

4 On the `draw:created` event, I'm capturing `e.layer` and adding a bunch of properties:

`var layer = e.layer;`

`layer.properties = { Title: 'Hello' };`

`features.addLayer(layer);`

`geo_features = features.toGeoJSON();`

However, my `geo_features` always have empty property attributes in each of the features and I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

iH8's [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35762144/revisions) was almost correct.

To specify properties that will appear in a vector layer's GeoJSON export (i.e. through its `.toGeoJSON()` method), you have to fill its `feature.type` and `feature.properties` members:

```js
var myVectorLayer = L.rectangle(...) // whatever

var feature = myVectorLayer.feature = myVectorLayer.feature || {};
feature.type = "Feature";
feature.properties = feature.properties || {};
feature.properties["Foo"] = "Bar";
```

Now `myVectorLayer.toGeoJSON()` returns a valid [GeoJSON feature object](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects) represented by:

```js
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Foo": "Bar"
    // More properties that may be pre-filled.
  },
  "geometry": // The vector geometry
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A (kind of ugly workaround) is using a `L.GeoJSON` layer and add the drawn layer's GeoJSON to it by using it's `addData` method. Afterwards grab the last layer in the `L.GeoJSON` layer's `_layers` object. At that point the layer has a valid GeoJSON `feature` property you can edit:

```js
var geojson = new L.GeoJSON().addTo(map);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: geojson
    }
}).addTo(map);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {

    geojson.addData(e.layer.toGeoJSON());

    var layers = geojson._layers,
        keys = Object.keys(layers),
        key = keys[keys.length - 1],
        layer = layers[key];

    layer.feature.properties = {
        'Foo': 'Bar'
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply iH8, but I can't get this to work. When injecting into e.layer.feature.properties it actually ends up on level too deep in GEOJsonObject.features[0].geometry.properties instead of GEOJsonObject.features[0].properties. This is causing Leaflet to throw "invalid GEOJson errors and not render anything"

Comment: Whoa, that's dumb :( Sorry for the confusion, should have tested it myself. I see now. Was sure that would work. Changed my answer to something that works, kinda ugly, but it does the trick. Let me know what you think. Good luck!

Comment: The first version would work if you also manually specify `layer.feature.type = "Feature"`. I got caught too.

Comment: @ghybs if you post it as an answer, I can mark it as such :)

Answer (score 0):

For your L.GeoJSON call include feature callback onEachFeature to options

```
    L.GeoJSON(featureData,{onEachFeature:function(feature,layer){

 //console.log(feature,layer);
 // do something like 

 feature.setStyle( convertLayerOptionsFromFeatureProperties( feature.properties ) );

}} )
```